# How to use ProcessBuilder or Nooj API in a Java project with intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, nlp

> Hello,

I'm working on a Java project that uses the Nooj library for linguistic analysis. I downloaded the JAR file of Nooj from the Nooj download page and added it as a dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nooj</groupId>
    <artifactId>nooj_api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${C:\Program Files\Java\Java NooJ\lib}</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

> My goal is to use the Nooj class to load a text file and apply grammatical rules to it. Here is the code I wrote for that:

```
import com.nooj.api.*;

public class TestNooj {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an instance of Nooj
        Nooj nooj = new Nooj();

        // Load the text file
        String input = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\test.txt";
        nooj.loadText(input);

        // Load the grammatical module
        String grammar = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\Java NooJ\\lib\\grammars\\french.noz";
        nooj.loadGrammar(grammar);

        // Apply the grammatical rules to the text
        nooj.applyGrammar();
    }
}
```

> However,when I import the classes of the Nooj API in my code (import com.nooj.api.*;), I get the following error message:

```
java: package com.nooj.api does not exist
```

> I tried to use ProcessBuilder to run the Nooj JAR file as an external process, but I didn't manage to get the expected results.
> How can I use ProcessBuilder or Nooj API in my Java project? What is the cause of the error message and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Why do you use `<systemPath>${C:\Program Files\Java\Java NooJ\lib}</systemPath>` ?? Does that jar exist as a jar file on your machine? If so install it into your local cache via `mvn install:install-file ... ` and use it as usual dependency...